# iframe content get notice when scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I display a pdf document inside an iframe and I want to check if user has read the document before he can validate my form.
It seems to be easy but after lots of try, I still not be able to do this.

I try many ways like implement scroll function like this :

```
$("#myFrame").scroll(function(){
if ($("#myFrame").scrollTop() + $("#myFrame").innerHeight() + 20 >= $("#myFrame")[0].scrollHeight) {
    alert("scroll is over");
}
});
```

and my iframe is :

```
<iframe id="myFrame" height="600" width="800" src="myDoc.pdf">
</iframe>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why `$("#myFrame")[0]`? What do you need the index for? Surely it's throwing an error?

Comment: Try accessing its content and you will be able to check the scroll position: `$("#myFrame").contents()`

Comment: Can't see how that approach would work for anybody where opening the pdf spawns an external program.

Comment: thanks for responses, the index was an error but it still not working without it, I never enter in function scroll even with .contents()...
you say that it can't work because of the external program, but how can I display a pdf document and get scroll informations ?

Answer (score 1):

This works flawlessly

```
$(function () {    
$("#iframeid").load(function () {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentWindow;
    $(iframe).scroll(function () {
        if (   $(iframe).scrollTop()==$(iframe).height()-$("#iframeid").height()) {
            alert("Reached bottom!");             
        }
    });
});
})
```